Adding values of cells
Bonjour,
i need to do basic operations on values in cells. For that i have developed a script but the values are added as in a string meaning that if a cell has the value 2 and the other one 3 it would return 23 instead of 5. I have tried parseInt but it returns #NUM.
I tried to retype the code using parseInt but it brings me a string instead of an integer. I can send the code if needed.
function Synthese() {
  const feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Synthèse Opérations');
  const Quantite = 0;
  const Frais = 0;
  const Valeur = 0;
  const TotalAchat = 0;
  const TotalVersements = 0;

  feuille.activate;
  feuille.getRange('A2:I10000').clearContent();
  let j = 0;
  let k = 0;
  for (let i = 2; i <= 10000; i++) {
    if (feuille.getRange(i, 11).getValue() == "") {
      break
    }
    i = i + j;
    k = j;
    j = 0;
    if (feuille.getRange(i, 11).getValue() == feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 11).getValue()) {
      let Quantite = parseInt(feuille.getRange(i, 15).getValue());
      let Frais = parseInt(feuille.getRange(i, 17).getValue());
      let Valeur = parseInt(feuille.getRange(i, 18).getValue());
      let TotalAchat = parseInt(feuille.getRange(i, 19).getValue());
      let TotalVersements = parseInt(feuille.getRange(i, 20).getValue());
      while (feuille.getRange(i + j, 11).getValue() == feuille.getRange(i + 1 + j, 11).getValue()) {
        feuille.getRange(i - k, 1).setValue(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 11).getValue());
        feuille.getRange(i - k, 2).setValue(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 12).getValue());
        feuille.getRange(i - k, 3).setValue(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 13).getValue());
        feuille.getRange(i - k, 4).setValue(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 14).getValue());

        Frais = Frais + parseInt(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 17).getValue());
        feuille.getRange(i - k, 6).setValue(Frais);
        if (feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 16).getValue() == "Achat") {
          Valeur = (Valeur * Quantite + (parseInt(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 18).getValue()) * parseInt(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 15).getValue()))) / (Quantite + parseInt(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 15).getValue()));
          feuille.getRange(i - k, 7).setValue(Valeur);
        } else {
          feuille.getRange(i - k, 7).setValue(Valeur);
        }
        if (feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 16).getValue() == "Vente") {
          Quantite = Quantite - parseInt(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 15).getValue());
          feuille.getRange(i - k, 5).setValue(Quantite);
        } else {
          Quantite = Quantite + parseInt(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 15).getValue());
          feuille.getRange(i - k, 5).setValue(Quantite);
        }
        TotalAchat = TotalAchat + parseInt(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 19).getValue());
        feuille.getRange(i - k, 8).setValue(TotalAchat);
        TotalVersements = TotalVersements + parseInt(feuille.getRange(i + j + 1, 20).getValue());
        feuille.getRange(i - k, 9).setValue(TotalVersements);
        j = j + 1;
      }
    } else {
      feuille.getRange(i - k - 1, 1).setValue(feuille.getRange(i, 11).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(i - k - 1, 2).setValue(feuille.getRange(i, 12).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(i - k - 1, 3).setValue(feuille.getRange(i, 13).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(i - k - 1, 4).setValue(feuille.getRange(i, 14).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(i - k - 1, 5).setValue(feuille.getRange(i, 15).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(i - k - 1, 6).setValue(feuille.getRange(i, 17).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(i - k - 1, 7).setValue(feuille.getRange(i, 18).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(i - k - 1, 8).setValue(feuille.getRange(i, 19).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(i - k - 1, 9).setValue(feuille.getRange(i, 20).getValue());
      j = 0;
    }
  }
};


Welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal, reproducible example: what are you using that function for, and how? What does your data look like? Where do you get your error? Also, please try to format (e.g. indent) your code as best as possible.

I agree with @user27425627, as that will help the community better understand your problem.

Use log at regular intervals to see what's going on.. For eg, console.log(Frais)  after the Frais

well i don't have an error the script works fine but the numbers just don't add up well they do but they add u as if they were strings...

i have run the log at some point and it just shows me that the numbers are added as a string and not as a basic operation

It is used to be able to summarize stocks with multiple entries. @user27425627

link

Use console.log(typeof someVariable) to see where exactly your numbers get converted to strings.

'TotalAchat = TotalAchat + feuille.getRange(i+j+1,19).getValue();' is the line where it becomes a string when the const TotalAchat is not empty.

Please make your sample sheet accessible to the public.

@Lou it's done link

Do all the rows contain a valid number in that cell?

@barmar i tend to think so. At least i have tried. They all are in the sheet called 'Opérations'

feuille.activate is missing () to call the method.

Can you remove all the code unrelated to this problem? It's hard to tell where the issue is.

i can yes but it's from the line where it sums up because i see the variable "TotalAchat" going red when i run the debug script. I don't know why it does that on this line and not others. Try to run the script and you'll see it pop up. Thank you so much @Barmar

Just to clarify... In the spreadsheet that you have provided, does sheet "Synthèse Opérations" represent the expected/desired outcome? If not, then please edit your spreadsheet to include the desired outcome.

The problem is NOT what you think. Certain cell values are blank and when included in formula, they have the effect of converting the result to a string. The code needs to watch specific column cells and/or variables and test for the value BEFORE a formula; an IF/ELSE can modify the formula depending on the input value.

aww many thanks for this solution and the master coding. I was a noob trying to code ;) I have modified the code now but i have the essence and why it converts to string now. Therefore i will change in the new code to check as you did in this solution. Thanks @Tedinoz

FYI, I initially tested whether certain values == “”  (blank) but found that this gave  inconsistent results. I found that testing typeof() == “string” is totally reliable. Please use this whenever appropriate.

You shared a spreadsheet (which included a script).  The answer below works on that spreadsheet and a modified version of that script. To be blunt: test wherever else you like but I have answered the question that you asked using the data and script that you provided.

yep @Tedinoz and thank you so much for this! you nailed it!

I am pleased that it has resolved your problem. You might care to “accept” the answer.

yes sorry i was not aware

Your script is recognising some values as strings.
The reason is that when any blank cell in Column S or T is used in a formula, the result will be a string.
Consider this answer based on your original code:
Major changes

var TotalAchat=0 and var TotalVersements=0

changed these from "const" because of repeated errors such as:

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'TotalVersements' before initialization


these errors were occurring because of instances where the variable was called before an earlier let. The OP may wish to return these variables to "const" and edit the code to their satisfaction.


let row = 1 and row =row+1

the existing code would overwrite the previous row when a new investment was added to the mix. The solution was:

increment a row variable each time the for loop was executed.
replace all instances of range row = i-k and i-k-1 with row




for (let i =2;i<=lastRow;i++) - the original code ran for 10000 rows (admittedly with a break as soon as a blank cell was found)

the code is modified to count the number of values in Column K  and calculate the "lastRow".
getlastRow does NOT work because the values are generated by formula.


// test for blank in Column T

the original formula is TotalVersements=feuille.getRange(i,20).getValue() however in the case of Achat, the value in Column T is blank.
 if (typeof(feuille.getRange(i,20).getValue()) == "string"){

added this test;
if a string, then TotalVersements = 0 else TotalVersements=feuille.getRange(i,20).getValue()




// test for Column S = blank (similar to the test for Column T)
// test for TotalVersements = blank (similar to others)


/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function Synthese() {
  const feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Synthèse Opérations');
  const Quantite=0;
  const Frais=0;
  const Valeur=0;
  var TotalAchat=0;
  var TotalVersements=0;

  feuille.activate;
  feuille.getRange('A2:I10000').clearContent();
  let j=0;
  let k=0;
  let row = 1

  // get the last row of data in in Column K 
  var kVals = feuille.getRange("K2:K").getValues();
  var kLast = kVals.filter(String).length;
  var lastRow = kLast+1
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the number of rows of data in column K = "+kLast+" and the last row = "+lastRow)

  // loop through data in range K:T
  for (let i =2;i<=lastRow;i++) {
    i=i+j;
    row =row+1
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: New row "+i+" target row = "+row)
    // test for no data
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: test for no data: i: "+i+", test range = "+feuille.getRange(i,11).getA1Notation()+", value = "+feuille.getRange(i,11).getValue())
    if (feuille.getRange(i,11).getValue()=="") {
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+" value is blank")
      break
    }

    k=j+k;
    j=0;

    // test for match on next row
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Test for match on next row: "+feuille.getRange(i,11).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i,11).getValue()+") with "+ feuille.getRange(i+j+1,11).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,11).getValue()+")")
    if (feuille.getRange(i,11).getValue() == feuille.getRange(i+j+1,11).getValue()) {
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: match on next row is true")
      let Quantite=feuille.getRange(i,15).getValue();
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Quantity Range = "+feuille.getRange(i,15).getA1Notation()+", value ="+feuille.getRange(i,15).getValue())
      let Frais=feuille.getRange(i,17).getValue();
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Frais = "+feuille.getRange(i,17).getA1Notation()+", value ="+feuille.getRange(i,17).getValue())
      let Valeur=feuille.getRange(i,18).getValue();
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Value Range = "+feuille.getRange(i,18).getA1Notation()+", value ="+feuille.getRange(i,18).getValue())
      TotalAchat=feuille.getRange(i,19).getValue();
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Total Purchase cost Range = "+feuille.getRange(i,19).getA1Notation()+", value ="+feuille.getRange(i,19).getValue())
      

      // test for blank in Column T
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: TotalVersements = range: "+feuille.getRange(i,20).getA1Notation()+", (value = "+feuille.getRange(i,20).getValue()+")")
      if (typeof(feuille.getRange(i,20).getValue()) == "string"){
        // column T is blank, so assign default value
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: value in Column T is blank so assign default value")
        TotalVersements = 0
      }
      else{
        // column T is NOT blank so include in formula
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Value in Column T is NOT blank so include in formula")
        TotalVersements=feuille.getRange(i,20).getValue()
      }
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: TotalVersements = "+TotalVersements)


      // while match the company on the next row
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: while match Company on next row: "+feuille.getRange(i+j,11).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j,11).getValue()+") equals  "+ feuille.getRange(i+1+j,11).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i+1+j,11).getValue()+")")
      while (feuille.getRange(i+j,11).getValue() == feuille.getRange(i+1+j,11).getValue()) {
       // Logger.log("DEBUG: Second Next row test is true")
    
        feuille.getRange(row,1).setValue(feuille.getRange(i+j+1,11).getValue());
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Enterprice: "+feuille.getRange(row,1).getA1Notation()+" = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,11).getA1Notation()+", value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,11).getValue())
        feuille.getRange(row,2).setValue(feuille.getRange(i+j+1,12).getValue());
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Code: "+feuille.getRange(row,2).getA1Notation()+" = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,12).getA1Notation()+", value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,12).getValue())
        feuille.getRange(row,3).setValue(feuille.getRange(i+j+1,13).getValue());
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Sector; "+feuille.getRange(row,3).getA1Notation()+" = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,13).getA1Notation()+", value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,13).getValue())
        feuille.getRange(row,4).setValue(feuille.getRange(i+j+1,14).getValue());
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Date: "+feuille.getRange(row,4).getA1Notation()+" = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,14).getA1Notation()+", value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,14).getValue())
   
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Frais before = "+Frais)   
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Frais next row = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,17).getA1Notation()+", value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,17).getValue())   
        Frais=Frais+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,17).getValue();
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Total Frais:  = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,17).getA1Notation()+", value = "+Frais)
        feuille.getRange(row,6).setValue(Frais);


        // test for ACHAT
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: test for ACHAT - if "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,16).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,16).getValue()+") = Achat")
        if (feuille.getRange(i+j+1,16).getValue()=="Achat") {
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: Price per share formula: first row; ('valeur' ("+Valeur+") by 'Quantite' ("+Quantite+") plus second row 'valeur' "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,18).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,18).getValue()+") by 'Quantite' "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getValue()+")) divided by ('first Quantite'="+Quantite+" plus 'second  Quantite' "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getValue()+"))")  
          Valeur=(Valeur*Quantite+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,18).getValue()*feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getValue())/(Quantite+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getValue());
          feuille.getRange(row,7).setValue(Valeur);
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: Price per share result: "+feuille.getRange(row,7).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+Valeur+")")
        } else {
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: SALE Value: "+feuille.getRange(row,7).getA1Notation()+" = "+Valeur)  
          feuille.getRange(row,7).setValue(Valeur);
        }
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: test for ACHAT: END")

        // test for VENTE
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: test for VENTE - if "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,16).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,16).getValue()+") = Vente")
        if (feuille.getRange(i+j+1,16).getValue()=="Vente") {
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: SALE: qty: "+Quantite+" less "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getA1Notation()+" (value ="+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getValue()+")")  
          Quantite=Quantite-feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getValue();
          feuille.getRange(row,5).setValue(Quantite);
        } else {
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: quantity purchased formula: qty: "+Quantite+" plus "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getA1Notation()+" (value ="+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getValue()+")")        
          Quantite=Quantite+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,15).getValue();
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: `Quantite` "+feuille.getRange(row,5).getA1Notation()+" = "+Quantite)
          feuille.getRange(row,5).setValue(Quantite);
        }
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: test for VENTE: END")

        // test for Column S = blank
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: test for Column S = blank")
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: TotalAChat = "+TotalAchat+" plus "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,19).getA1Notation()+" (value= "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,19).getValue()+")")
        // console.log("DEBUG: typeof-BEFORE: TotalAchat type = "+typeof(TotalAchat));
        if (typeof(feuille.getRange(i+j+1,19)) == "string"){
          // column S is blank, so exclude column S from formula
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: value in Column S is blank so exclude Column S from formula")
          TotalAchat = TotalAchat            
        }
        else{
          // column S is NOT blank, so include column S in formula
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: value in Column S is NOT blank so include Column S in formula")
          TotalAchat = TotalAchat + feuille.getRange(i+j+1,19).getValue();
        }
        // console.log("DEBUG: typeof-AFTER: TotalAchat type = "+typeof(TotalAchat));

        // Logger.log("DEBUG: TotalAChat: "+feuille.getRange(row,8).getA1Notation()+ " = "+TotalAchat)
        feuille.getRange(row,8).setValue(TotalAchat);


        // check if total sales value (column T) has a numeric value
        // if no, then assign default value
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: test for a blank in Column T")
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Total sales = Totalversements = "+TotalVersements+" plus "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,20).getA1Notation()+" (value = "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,20).getValue()+")")
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: cell "+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,20).getA1Notation()+" type of "+typeof(feuille.getRange(i+j+1,20).getValue()))
        if (typeof(feuille.getRange(i+j+1,20).getValue()) =="string"){
          // Column T is blank, so exclude from formula
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: BLANK: Column T is blank, so exclude from formula")
        }
        else{
          // Column T is NOT blank, so exclude from formula
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: NOT BLANK: Column T is not blank, so include in  formula")
          TotalVersements = TotalVersements+feuille.getRange(i+j+1,20).getValue();
        }
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: typeof-AFTER: TotalVersements type = "+typeof(TotalVersements)+" value = "+TotalVersements)


        // test for TotalVersements = blank
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: test for TotalVersements is blank")
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Total Versements = "+TotalVersements+" typeof = "+typeof(TotalVersements))
        if (typeof(TotalVersements) == "string"){
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: totalversements is blank so assign default value")
          TotalVersements = 0
        }
        feuille.getRange(row,9).setValue(TotalVersements)

        // if qty is zero, then reset variables
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: qty = "+Quantite+", if zero then reset variables")
        if (Quantite==0) {
          TotalAchat = 0;
          Frais=0;
          TotalVersements=0;
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: qty = 0, so TotalAchat, TotalVersements and Frais set to zero")
        }
        j=j+1;
      } // end of while
    } else 
    {
      // no match on next row
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Next row test is false")
      // test for blank values
      feuille.getRange(row,1).setValue(feuille.getRange(i,11).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(row,2).setValue(feuille.getRange(i,12).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(row,3).setValue(feuille.getRange(i,13).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(row,4).setValue(feuille.getRange(i,14).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(row,5).setValue(feuille.getRange(i,15).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(row,6).setValue(feuille.getRange(i,17).getValue());
      feuille.getRange(row,7).setValue(feuille.getRange(i,18).getValue());
      // test for blank in Column S
      if (typeof(feuille.getRange(i,19).getValue()) == "string"){
        feuille.getRange(row,8).setValue(0);
      }
      else{
        feuille.getRange(row,8).setValue(feuille.getRange(i,19).getValue());
      }
      // test for blank in Column T
      if (typeof(feuille.getRange(i,20).getValue()) == "string"){
        feuille.getRange(row,9).setValue(0);
      }
      else{
        feuille.getRange(row,9).setValue(feuille.getRange(i,20).getValue());
      }
      j=0;
    }
} // end of for loop
Logger.log("DEBUG: End of processing")
}


SAMPLE INPUT

SAMPLE OUTPUT



